# For Dagger 2, what is the best way to access an instance inside 1 module from other modules?

Tags: android, dagger-2

Just trying out Dagger 2 in an Android app and I feel like there might be a much simpler solution to what I am trying to achieve.

I have 2 modules:

- `ApplicationModule` where its life cycle is tied to the entire application as the name implies.
- `UserModule` is created whenever a user is logged in.

Now say I have a singleton `Prefs` instance that is created in the `ApplicationModule`, but I need to access it in the classes inside the `UserModule`, what is the best way to go about this? Currently I am creating it in the ApplicationModule, and then passing it into the constructor of the UserModule whenever it is created. Is there a way to avoid doing that and let Dagger manage this for me?

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Prefs prefs() {
        return new Prefs();
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules={ApplicationModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    Prefs providePrefs();
}

@Module
public class UserModule {
    private Prefs prefs;

    public UserModule(Prefs prefs) {
        // Anyway to avoid having to do this?
        this.prefs = prefs;
    } 

    @Provides
    @UserScope
    public UserService userService() {
        // Possible to get the prefs from the ApplicationComponent?
        return new UserService(this.prefs);
    }
}

@Component(dependencies = {ApplicationComponent.class}, modules = {UserModule.class})
@UserScope
public interface UserComponent extends ApplicationComponent {
    UserService provideUserService();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of dagger is to let it resolve dependencies for you. You don't need to pass in anything into your modules, that is not directly needed, like the actual user for the user module.

Dependencies will be resolved by dagger. In your case this means adapting your code like this:

```
@Module
public class UserModule {

    public UserModule() {
        // way of avoiding this code ;)
    }

    @Provides
    @UserScope
    public UserService userService(Prefs prefs) {
        return new UserService(prefs);
    }
}
```

This way *dagger* will provide the dependency to the method. You don't have to do it yourself.

The prerequisites for this to work are that the dependencies can actually be provided. In your case `Prefs` is provided by the application component. As long as you instantiate a `@Subcomponent` or in your case dependent `@Component` with an exposed dependency, it will work—the `Prefs providePrefs()` method in your app component.

This will also work if the module providing the dependency is in the same component.

---

If your `UserService` depends on nothing else, you could even think about removing the whole module, since it looks like it can be provided by constructor injection.

```
@UserScope
public class UserService {

    Prefs prefs;

    @Inject
    public UserService(Prefs prefs) {
        this.prefs = prefs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response David, the examples help alot. I do have 1 confusion, if I remove the parameter in the UserModule constructor like you did in your example, would UserService get created before UserModule is created? Since UserService now has its dependency fulfilled, if so then would even putting UserService inside UserModule enforce anything?

Comment: @Mike You need a UserModule to create your component, so it would be created before. This should not have an impact though. Modules are just to provide dependencies if they can't be created by dagger itself